# How to connect uv map in shader editor

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor

How can I connect the uv map node with the bsdf principled node?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Texture Coordinates Node and select UV and plug that to the Vector input of your texture. Then plug in the color output of the texture to the socket where you need the texture on the Principled BSDF node (most likely in the Base Color input, but you don't specify the use of the texture in the question).

Alternatively use Input UV map node.